# finding the derivative of a function when the function definition isn't given (multi variable)

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

[image]

I'm not sure what to do here with these given values. I can't find an example online or in my book similar to this. I have a feeling I'm probably supposed to use the chain rule, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this problem. Can someone please give me some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: i figured it out actually but I'm not sure why. I used chain rule case 2 and did (2)(-3) + (8)(6) = 42. but I'm not sure why you can just use g'(2)  and h'(2) for dx/dt and dy/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule is exactly what you’re supposed to use here. It tells us that $$p'(t) = f_x(g(t),h(t))\,g'(t)+f_y(g(t),h(t))\,h'(t).$$ Plug in the known values: $$p'(2)=f_x(4,5)\,g'(2)+f_y(4,5)\,h'(2) = 2\cdot(-3)+8\cdot6=42.$$